# Field value increase by 1

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to update records in `db` and increase a value by 1. I tried it on SQL Management Studio and it worked fine, but in a php script nothing happens:

```
UPDATE db SET
status='active',
times = ((SELECT times FROM db WHERE status='notactive') + '1')
WHERE
status='notactive'
```

Is it possible to use special functions for this problem? I mean a special function for increasing value by 1?

Comment: How many records for `notactive` status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET status = 'active',
    times = times + 1
WHERE status = 'notactive'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  db SET
        status = 'active',
        times = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(times),0) + 1 FROM db WHERE status = 'notactive')
WHERE   status = 'notactive'
```